# How to manage unarmed combat?

Tags: middle-earth-role-playing, unarmed-combat

In MERP it seems that there is no combat table for unarmed combat: bare punchs and kicks, like those a character may face in a tavern, where unsheathing a sword may put the combat beyond the acceptable limits of a drunken fight.

But instead tables seem to be able to cope only with armed combat.

How could a punch be managed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The brawling/punching skill is missing from MERP**

The direct implementation is listed on table CST-2 page 68

> "***The attackers OB is his strength bonus plus his agility bonus"

Punches/Kicks use the "Tooth and Claw" table using Unbalancing crits with a maximum of an "A" crit. Note the maximum attack value will depend on the creatures/characters size (Medium for humans/elves)

I suggest adding a "Brawl" combat skill, treat it the same as any other combat skill, if you do add this then the stat bonus should only be Strength (not ST+AG) like any other Melee OB.